# #if macros in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macros

I am trying to define the value of a macro based on some condition like

```
#define DEV NO
#if DEV == YES
#define API_ENDPOINT_HOST @"https://my-dev.com/"
#else
#define API_ENDPOINT_HOST @"http://my-qa.com/"
#endif
```

But even though I have defined DEV as No, it is always taking `API_ENDPOINT_HOST` as `@"https://my-dev.com/"`. What is wrong here?

Comment: You need to use numeric values, e.g. `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Even Uli's answer is correct (as everyone expected), I want to explain it in more detail:

In PP phase an undefined identifier in an `#if` directive is replaced with 0. `NO` and `YES` are not defined anymore as macro as it has been in the past, but became literals. So they are undefined in PP phase.

Your second line is:

```
#if DEV == YES
```

`DEV` is replaced with `NO` …,

```
#if NO == YES
```

… what is undefined as `YES` is. Therefore both are replaced by 0:

```
#if 0 == 0
```

That's obviously true.

Answer (score 1):

NO and YES are Objective-C constructs. The preprocessor runs before the Objective-C compiler, so does not know YES or NO yet. Usually people use 0 and 1 in preprocessor defines.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, just define your symbol and then use `#ifdef` instead of `#if`.

```
#define DEV

#ifdef DEV
  #define API_ENDPOINT_HOST @"https://my-dev.com/"
#else
  #define API_ENDPOINT_HOST @"http://my-qa.com/"
#endif
```